# Can a vb file with assigned property values be cached WITH the values?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, gridview, xmldatasource

I have a web application that (a.) collects information from a user, (b.) stores this information as properties in a vb file in the \APP_CODE directory, (c.) loads a form with a gridview, and (d.) populates the gridview with data from an xmldatasource using an XPATH derived from values (properties) in the vb file.

My question: can this vb file be cached WITH the current values?  The gridview displays external links, and when the user comes back, page turns in the grid won’t work without the vb file data.
Any help on this and any suggestions about the optimal way to employ caching for an application such as this or a better way to pass multiple values from one page to another will be most appreciated.

Comment: VB files are just files on disk. Your question doesn't make much sense. Do you know what objects are?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  If it's JUST a file on a disk, how can you create properties in it and store and retrieve variables using these properties?  Where do the variables actually get stored?  How would you get a bunch of variables from one form to another?

Comment: Ok, "Programming 011" here, it's a file that represents part of a computer program. Once compiled or interpreted, the results of the compilation or interpretation may have properties, which may have values. The file is just a text file.

Comment: If you have the data, in any shape or form, you can cache it using this: `HttpRuntime.Cache`. Look into it so you can see how to make it expire and stuff.

Comment: OK, so are these results -- presumably objects -- addressable and cacheable?  Some structure created from the vb template is holding the variables (properties) in memory someplace ... is in it protected memory that doesn't have anything to do with the locals window?